# Command not found after &&

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments, gulp, bower

Why this is not executing?

`git clone app.git && cd app && npm install && bower install && gulp`
*output* gulp: command not found

Either this

`git clone app.git && cd app && npm install && bower install ; gulp`
*output* gulp: command not found

But only

`git clone app.git && cd app && npm install && bower install` then `gulp`

Is there any way to execute `gulp` inside chain?

#### Please Note:

Gulp is already globally installed with `npm install -g gulp`

Running gulp in nonsense directory throws

```
[04:24:57] Local gulp not found in ~/dev/projects/repoint
[04:24:57] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Which means its installed globally installed.

For demo, please grab this repo and execute:

```
git clone https://github.com/vko-online/metro.git && cd metro && npm install && bower install && gulp
```

Comment: Do you have global gulp installed?

Comment: Is there a space before the error `gulp: command not found`?

Comment: Works for me -> `git clone https://github.com/vko-online/metro.git && cd metro && npm install && bower install && gulp`

Comment: @evc: You didn't paste the two lines (shell command + response) in a single code segment, so it is not possible to see whether there was a space or whether the word `gulp` is at the left-hand margin.

Comment: @evc: By the way, quoting the SO input form's help information (under the Code menu): "To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces: "

Comment: I didn't have errors with this setup: osx 10.10.1, bash 4.3, node 0.10.35, npm 2.1.17, gulp 3.8.10

Comment: Strange. I cannot execute it.  Linux precise 12

Comment: @rici Thanks. Tomorrow will edit. I'm sitting from phone

Comment: What does the command `type gulp` emit? If it doesn't give a path to where `gulp` is installed, then it's not properly installed -- which is very much the obvious/likely answer here.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your shell had hashed a path to an old local installation which you'd since replaced with a global install. That would be specific to the shell session -- meaning you _wouldn't_ get that error if you simply opened a new window, or ran `hash -r` to clear the location cache.

Comment: In any event, `&&` doesn't change how PATH searches are done to run executables, so it can't possibly be at fault.

Answer (score 1):

If the semi-colon variant doesn't work then `gulp` is not in your path, plain and simple. *That's* the problem you need to fix.

Fixing it may involve installing `gulp` or it may be as simple as modifying your path to include the directory where it's installed.

Comment: It's already global. Problem maybe in two versions of gulp? I have global one. And also npm install in chain also install it in current folder. ?

Answer (score 0):

[As pointed out in the doc](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md), you should install it globally and add it to your project dev deps locally:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

Comment: A little hackish way but it works on my machine:
`git clone https://github.com/vko-online/metro.git && cd metro && npm install && bower install &&
 sudo npm install --global gulp && gulp` for some reason local installation of gulp somehow overrides global one? (i'm not node guy)

Comment: Could you check your gulp versions, because, after this way of install (in prev comment), old command that you have in question works just fine.

Comment: So problem in different versions of gulp? Global old /local new

Comment: Probably, on my machine with same versions first command (one with `&& gulp`) works fine. Can you make test, to verify that?